# Join two rows which have same value in two column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is printscreen image of my table.

[image]

I have a MySQL table named "table". When I wrote "`SELECT * FROM table`" in the while loop, I want to get one time same values of "fikraNo" and "maddeNo". But if fikraNo and maddeNo have same value, "icerik" must be joined.
For example when I want to get all values from the table, the output must be like this:

```
1   1   174     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
2   2   174     1500'lerden beri kullanılan standart Lorem Ipsum...
3   3   174     Nullam mollis accumsan quam eget aliquet. Ut sit a...
4   1   135     Phasellus ac massa neque. Nunc blandit, nibh sit a...
5   2   135     Nulla id placerat odio. Fusce quis porttitor dui. ...
6   0   135     Vestibulum elit neque, ultrices ac consequat vitae...
7   1   134     Etiam dignissim, lacus sed faucibus auctor, felis ...
8   2   134     Vestibulum rhoncus ultricies arcu id feugiat. Null...
9   1   133     Donec sit amet nunc urna. Vivamus id dui velit, ac...
10  0   133     Maecenas aliquet pellentesque egestas. Vestibulum ...
11  0   109     armut dalda kız balkonda sallanır vay vay...
12  1   109     Duis consequat luctus rhoncus. Etiam ante lectus, ...
14  3   116     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
15  0   2       This is the first item in the first field.
16  0   2       And this is the second item in second field.
```

Could you help me, how do I manage this?
Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an aggregate function to concatenate together the `icerik`s, and if you also want to show the minimum id, you also need an aggregate function to get that.

This should do the job:

```
SELECT MIN(id),
       fikraNo,
       maddeNo,
       GROUP_CONCAT(icerik ORDER BY id DESC SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM `table`
GROUP BY fikraNo, maddeNo
```

Demonstration here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7c93/1

Comment: Thank you very much. Pill for my headache. :)